# Dynamically select table names from VS Data tool

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have a SSIS package that syncs data from source to destination Tables. However I am looking for a solution where whenever the package runs it automatically selects table from previous month i.e. (TableName-1).  for example <102019> at the end of tablename.

I have used something as below in the SSIS package via VS Data tool's source but did not worked. I got error any further steps I have to do?

```
declare @year varchar(200) = 'TABLE1'
set @year = @year + CONCAT(DATEPART(mm,getdate())-1,DATEPART(yyyy,getdate()))
select @year as result
```

Comment: I don't get an error with that code: [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9e2682fbdd4ac0e998817f6f33f57966). If you are getting an error, include it in your question, and provide us a way to replicate it.

Answer (score 0):

Chaitanya, Your query running properly and getting matched output that you want.

[image]

Are you looking for any other options for that??

Comment: but when i use the same from Visual Studio source OLE DB "sql command", this does not work. Is there any other potential solution that i can try instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could also attack your problem from the information_schema side.

```
declare @LastMo date = dateadd(month,-1,getdate())
declare @LastMoText  varchar(6) = right('0' + cast(month(@LastMo) as varchar(2)) , 2)
                       + cast(Year(@LastMo) as varchar(4))

select table_name
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables
where left(TABLE_NAME,6) = 'table1'
    and right(table_name,6) = @LastMoText
```

This would let you know if the table exists. And therefore, your package would not fail if you put that into a foreach loop.

1. Exec SQL --> above SQL and stored result in ADO.Object variable.
2. Foreach ADO object
3. Store each loop in to variable called @table
4. Set @SQL = "SELECT * FROM " + @table
5. Add Dataflow and source from @SQL

Comment: I fixed your logic for last month as well. What would happen in January using your logic?